# MYSQL Friday grouping for report

Tags: mysql

We need to run reports on Friday to Friday basis for the entire year. I do not see `week()` function handy for this.

Say we have a table `Summary`, having two columns - `count` and `creation_date`. I need to aggregate counts based on `creation_date` spanning from Friday to Friday. This needs to be run for a couple of years.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is week() inappropriate?

Comment: Week has Sunday, Monday as start boundaries.

Comment: Couldn't that be resolved with 'my_date-INTERVAL 2 DAY'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query to tell you the previous Friday and the following Thursday from today

```
SELECT DATE(week_beg),DATE(week_end) FROM
(SELECT daywk_beg + INTERVAL 0 second week_beg,
daywk_beg + INTERVAL 604799 second week_end
FROM (SELECT (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL daysbacktoday DAY) daywk_beg
FROM (SELECT SUBSTR('2345601',wkndx,1) daysbacktoday
FROM (SELECT DAYOFWEEK(dt) wkndx FROM (SELECT DATE(NOW()) dt)
AAAAA) AAAA) AAA) AA) A;
```

Here is today's results

```
mysql> SELECT DATE(week_beg),DATE(week_end) FROM
    -> (SELECT daywk_beg + INTERVAL 0 second week_beg,
    -> daywk_beg + INTERVAL 604799 second week_end
    -> FROM (SELECT (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL daysbacktoday DAY) daywk_beg
    -> FROM (SELECT SUBSTR('2345601',wkndx,1) daysbacktoday
    -> FROM (SELECT DAYOFWEEK(dt) wkndx FROM (SELECT DATE(NOW()) dt)
    -> AAAAA) AAAA) AAA) AA) A;
+----------------+----------------+
| DATE(week_beg) | DATE(week_end) |
+----------------+----------------+
| 2013-03-22     | 2013-03-28     |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

[I wrote a query like this in the DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6045/how-can-i-improve-my-sql-statement-with-weekly-results-with-week-starting-on-thu/6050#6050)

Here is a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE summary
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    ...
    `count` int not null default 0,
    creation_date date,
    primary key (id)
);
```

To get your query to tally results based on Fridays, you need this

```
SELECT SUM(`count`) count_sum,friday FROM
(SELECT `count`,DATE(week_beg) friday
(SELECT daywk_beg + INTERVAL 0 second week_beg,
daywk_beg + INTERVAL 604799 second week_end,`count`
FROM (SELECT `count`,(DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL daysbacktoday DAY) daywk_beg
FROM (SELECT `count`,SUBSTR('2345601',wkndx,1) daysbacktoday
FROM (SELECT `count`,DAYOFWEEK(dt) wkndx FROM
(SELECT `count`,creation_date FROM dt)
AAAAA) AAAA) AAA) AA) A) fri
GROUP BY friday;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
count, creation_date,
from
(
    SELECT 
    count, creation_date
    DATEDIFF(week, '2013-03-30', date) AS WeekNumber
    FROM Summary
)
GROUP BY
count,
creation_date,
WeekNumber
```

You would enter your start date in place of `2013-03-30`

Comment: I do want to generate the report as one time effort. I do not want to have cron job for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by

```
YEARWEEK(`date` - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

or you can calculate your `start_week_date` and `end_week_date` with this:

```
SELECT
  `date`,
  `date` - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(`date`) + 1) % 7 DAY start_week_date,
  `date` + INTERVAL 6 - (DAYOFWEEK(`date`) + 1) % 7 DAY end_week_date
FROM
  dates
```

Please see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66686/1).

So your query could be like this:

```
SELECT
  creation_date - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(creation_date) + 1) % 7 DAY start_week_date,
  SUM(count)  --- or your aggregate function
FROM
  Summary
GROUP BY
  creation_date - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(creation_date) + 1) % 7 DAY start_week_date
```